# Сохранение изображения с камеры в память телефона(android). Не могу найти файл

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Не могу найти файл, который делаю с помощью камеры в приложении. Пробовал изменять путь сохранения, но это не к чему не приводит. Буду очень благодарен за помощь.
P. S. В файле манифеста все разрешения прописаны

```
  private void takePicture() {
                if(cameraDevice == null)
                    return;
                CameraManager manager = (CameraManager)getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
                try{
                    CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraDevice.getId());
                    Size[] jpegSizes = null;
                    if(characteristics != null)
                        jpegSizes = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP)
                                .getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);

                    //Capture image with custom size
                    int width = 640;
                    int height = 480;
                    if(jpegSizes != null && jpegSizes.length > 0)
                    {
                        width = jpegSizes[0].getWidth();
                        height = jpegSizes[0].getHeight();
                    }
                    final ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width,height,ImageFormat.JPEG,1);
                    List<Surface> outputSurface = new ArrayList<>(2);
                    outputSurface.add(reader.getSurface());
                    outputSurface.add(new Surface(textureView.getSurfaceTexture()));

                    final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
                    captureBuilder.addTarget(reader.getSurface());
                    captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);

                    //Check orientation base on device
                    int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
                    captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION,ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));

                    file = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory()+"/My files/"+UUID.randomUUID().toString()+".jpg");
                    ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readerListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader imageReader) {
                            Image image = null;
                            try{
                                image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                                ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                                byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
                                buffer.get(bytes);
                                save(bytes);

                            }
                            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            catch (IOException e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            finally {
                                {
                                    if(image != null)
                                        image.close();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        private void save(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
                            OutputStream outputStream = null;
                            try{
                                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                                outputStream.write(bytes);
                            }finally {
                                if(outputStream != null)
                                    outputStream.close();
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(readerListener,mBackgroundHandler);
                    final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureListener = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                            super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Saved "+file, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            createCameraPreview();
                        }
                    };

                    cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(outputSurface, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                            try{
                                cameraCaptureSession.capture(captureBuilder.build(),captureListener,mBackgroundHandler);
                            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {

                        }
                    },mBackgroundHandler);


                } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Comment: рантайм разрешения раздаются? save(byte[] bytes) отрабатывает? просто даже если байты уплыли, то из Java file = new File() его создаст если путь доступен (кстати моежет проверять он bool возвращает), попробуйте вначале просто создать файл до записи данных в него, как получится можете уже втаскивать вашу портянку, если что отпишите

Answer (score 1):

Разве у Вас в логах нет ошибок и они не дают понять, что файл не создан и не записан? `Environment.getDataDirectory()` - это служебная папка и писать в неё не следует, даже если получится.
Замените на [`Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(String type)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)), например.
В его документации как раз и пример сохранения изображения с оповещением `MediaScanner`, к тому же, что бы она появилась в галерее.

Когда Вы хотите записать в свою подпапку её нужно сначала создать методом [`mkdir()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File#mkdir()) или [`mkdirs()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File#mkdirs()) для нескольких вложенных разом.

И, наконец, начиная с Android 6.0 (API level 23) разрешения в манифесте не достаточно - некоторые (чтение/запись в том числе) нужно проверять и запрашивать во время выполнения.
Документация: [Request App Permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)